# Google translation with flags should not get redirect to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I am using google's language picker with countries flags by using following code in template file in wordpress.

```
           <!-- Add English to Chinese (Simplified) BETA -->

           <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/translate?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&langpair=en%7Czh-CN&hl=en&ie=UTF8'); return false;" title="Google-Translate-Chinese (Simplified) BETA"><img border="0" style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;" width="19" alt="Google-Translate-Chinese (Simplified) BETA" src="https://sites.google.com/site/translationflags/images/_chinese_s.png" height="19" title="Google-Translate-Chinese (Simplified) BETA"/></a>

           <!-- END English to Chinese (Simplified) BETA-->



         <!-- Add English to French -->

             <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/translate?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&langpair=en%7Cfr&hl=en&ie=UTF8'); return false;" title="Google-Translate-English to French "><img border="0" style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;" width="19" alt="Google-Translate-English to French " src="https://sites.google.com/site/translationflags/images/_french_s.png" height="19" title="Google-Translate-English to French "/></a>
             ...

             ...
```

When we click on flag in the webpage, it gets redirected to other page(google's translation page). And there the page gets translated to other language.But I want  it shouldn't get redirected to other page instead it should translate on the same page like by using simple google translation code with dropdown option. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need : --

```
<div id="google_translate_element" style="float:left; padding-left:15px">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',  multilanguagePage: true,
layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT},     'google_translate_element');
}
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?    cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

try this